# Error while trying to port a repo from github

Tags: python

There is a github code I am trying to use that is located [here](https://github.com/PX4/pyulog).

I am trying to run `params.py` which is a code that will take a binary file and converts it so that I can plot it (or so I think).

I tried to run:

```
pip install git+https://github.com/PX4/pyulog.git
```

However, that gave me an error:

```
C:\Users\Mike\Documents>pip install git+https://github.com/PX4/pyulog.git
Collecting git+https://github.com/PX4/pyulog.git
  Cloning https://github.com/PX4/pyulog.git to c:\users\mike\appdata\local\temp\pip-t_vvh_b0-build
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\tokenize.py", line 454, in open
        buffer = _builtin_open(filename, 'rb')
    FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\Mike\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-t_vvh_b0-build\\setup.py'
```

Comment: Looks like an Anaconda issue. I'd suggest to first clone the repo then worry about installing it so that you can disentangle Github from the problem.

Comment: @Hack-R Could you please provide a source for me to do that? I thought what I was doing was cloning it.

Comment: Per the error message, there is no `setup.py` file in that repo, which is how `pip` is trying to install it.

Comment: You just type `git clone https://github.com/PX4/pyulog.git`. Assuming you have git installed (if not, install git).

Comment: @Hack-R So when I clone it. using git clone github.com/PX4/pyulog.git. How do I access params.py so that I can run it on a data file?

Answer (score 1):

Pip install tries to install the module from :

- PyPI (and other indexes) using requirement specifiers.
- VCS project urls.
- Local project directories.
- Local or remote source archives.

When looking at the items to be installed, pip checks what type of item each is, in the following order:

- Project or archive URL.
- local directory (which must contain a **setup.py**, or pip will report an error).
- Local file (a sdist or wheel format archive, following the naming conventions for those formats).
- A requirement, as specified in PEP 440.

In your case, git repo doesn't meet the requirement. It doesn't have setup.py that's why you get the error.
Instead try cloning the repo on your local machine.

Comment: So when I clone it. using git clone https://github.com/PX4/pyulog.git. How do I access params.py so that I can run it on a data file?

Comment: @MikeJones just make sure it's on your Python path, either editing the path or moving the cloned repo accordingly. Then you can `import` from it.

Comment: @MikeJones : once you clone it, it will be in your local repo, use that path to read param.py as stated by jonrsharpe.

Comment: @NishuTayal I am a bit confused. I am sorry if I am coming as a total newbie and asking so many questions. I imported locally, and when I run import pyulog It just says pyulog imported but not used so that means it is imported correct I do see a folder called pyulog in my python directory where my code resides? Now that I have done that how do I know what syntax to use to call a file into one of pyulog scripts (params.py)?